# How do I build an array using values I pull from multiple .csv file data sets? - Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am fairly new to coding and python and have reached a point where I do not know how to proceed. I have hundreds of .csv files, each with a time column and multiple columns of data. I need to pull the max and min values from the data columns and write that information to an array which I can then save to an excel data file for analysis. My data looks like this:

```
Time Data1 Data2 Data3
1     0      0     0
2     1      1     1
3     2      3     4
4     5      6     7
```

I want my final array to look like this:

```
FileName    MaxData1   MinData1  ...  ...
File1           5           0    ...  ...
File2          ...         ...   ...  ...
```

My current code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

FilePath = 'File1.csv'
ImportedFile = pd.read_csv(FilePath, sep=',') 

Data = ImportedFile.values
del ImportedFile

Time = Data[:, 0]
Data1 = Data[:,1]
Data2 = Data[:,2]
Data3 = Data[:,3]

Max1 = np.nanmax(Data1)
Min1 = np.nanmin(Data1)
Max2 = np.nanmax(Data2)
Min2 = np.nanmin(Data2)
Max3 = np.nanmax(Data3)
Min3 = np.nanmin(Data3)

Results = np.array([("File1", Max1, Min1, Max2, Min2, Max3, Min3)])
```

So my question is two-part. 1)How do I iterate between file while pulling the data I want? and 2) How do I write to an ever expanding array and save to an excel or .csv file?

Comment: your final array [which i think is a dataframe] will have 2 columns per column in the file? for example if your csv file has data1, data2, data3, you want the final array to have maxdata1, mindata1, maxdata2, mindata2, maxdata3, mindata3?

Comment: If i understand you're question correctly, yes. Each column of data in the original file will be distilled down to two columns (max and min) in the final output. So the first column of output array will be the file name (a test number) followed by columns of max and min values pulled from the original data recordings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use glob to fetch all the csvs at once and store them in an array. then you can create an array of the column names that the csvs have. iterate over the two and within each iteration perform your required min/max logic.

Comment: I'm not sure that fetching and storing all csvs at once will work due to memory restrictions. Each data file (csv) i have contains 6 columns of 100,000 data points. The example I gave of the file structure is highly simplified.

Comment: So what I believe I need to do is open a csv -> read max min values -> store values in an array -> close/delete file -> repeat. I'm not sure how to do this. Really, I've only been able to open the csv and read max and min values. I'm seeking guidance on how to iterate between files and storing max.min values in an array that grows with each new data set analyzed.

Comment: using glob you can fetch all the csv file names and store that in an array, just the names. then iterate through that array passing the name along to read one file at a time.